# how to reset scroll position in a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I am working on a mobile hybrid application.

In my html page, I have 3 tabs. When clicking a tab, the content of the scrollable div gets changed. My problem is when I scroll down the content of div (view) and click another tab, the content disappears (but the content is there). Please help me so I can reset the div scroll position when clicking any tab.

Please give me suggestions only with JavaScript or CSS, not with JQuery as I am not using the JQuery library.

Comment: `_Please suggest me only with javascript_` You should not add jquery tag if not interested in most interestingly simplified js library.

Comment: I have include jquery tag jsut because to maximize the view and as You know jquery is Javascript library.

Comment: Then you should have included `pron` tag as well `:p` just kidding

Comment: Down voters, Please put the reason(s) for down voting :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally this worked for me

```
function resetScrollPos(selector) {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (var p = 0; p < divs.length; p++) {
    if (Boolean(divs[p].style.transform)) { //for IE(10) and firefox
      divs[p].style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';
    } else { //for chrome and safari
      divs[p].style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';
    }
  }
}
resetScrollPos('.mblScrollableViewContainer');
```

Calling this function after transition between view ,will reset my scroll position.

Answer (score 52):

Without seeing code, i can just guess.
If you want to reset the scroll position you can simply use

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

add this code to your each tab click functions so that when ever you click any tab, it resets to top.

If you have any specific div that has overflow property

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('specificDiv');
myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: shadow, this is not working for me, I have used this before. thanks

Comment: @anand4tech can you set up a fiddle

Comment: My code and logic is bit complex to show you on fiddle. if you could provide me any reference according to my requirements. Thanks

Comment: setting scrollTop DOES work, but if your div is hidden when you set it, it does not appear to work.  set the scrollTop to zero AFTER you unhide it.

Comment: Apart from the advice by @TimothyRyan above, also ensure the div you want to `scrollTop` has the `overflow-y` property. The writer of the answer also mentions this, but should have stressed it more since it is a potential pitfall

Answer (score 6):

It is easy

```
 <div id="test" style="height:150px; width:600px;overflow-y:auto;background-color:gray;">
     <div style="width:150px;height:500px; background-color:green;"></div>
 </div>
```

> ```
> document.getElementById('test').scrollTop =0;
> ```

Comment: It is not necessarily the DIV you are in but could be a UL you need to scroll

Answer (score 1):

i used this on my inverted comments section and it worked.
instead of id i had class.
i needed for scrollbar to be at the bottom each time user adds comment.
so i put this on submit button.

```
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('comments-container');
myDiv[0].scrollTop = 0;
```