# Android set scrollLeft while updating content on scroll event does not update scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, scroll, touch

[Setting scrollLeft does reset the scroll bar position](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/zujxaqy3/29/) and [updating the content works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/zujxaqy3/17/) but when [doing both at the same time](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/zujxaqy3/10/embedded/result/) the scroll bar gets confused and doesn't reset.

To see the expected behavior vs unexpected behavior view each demo on a device with a touchpad and use the touchpad to scroll left or right inside the wrapper, then try to do the same thing on an android device.

Notice that on a laptop the element will scroll endlessly, on an android device the element will scroll only until it has reached the initially set "max scroll"

What should happen:

When the user scrolls left or right, move the first child element to the end of the nodeList or move the last child to the beginning and reset the scroll position to that of half the with of the first child.

The following are my attempts at fixing the issue

1. Set `transform: translateX(0px)` on `.inner` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492776/how-to-reset-scroll-position-in-a-div-using-javascript/22217774#22217774) which had worse behavior than before.
2. the fix listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641898/jquery-scrollleft-not-working-on-android) which was for a previous bug in android where setting scrollLeft did not work at all. This did not help the issue at all.
3. `wrap.appendChild(inner)` on each scroll event, which slowed the scrolling down but didnt fix the issue because chrome remembers scroll positions. This would be a hack even if I could get chrome to forget the scroll position (which looks like it could be plausible but would be yet another hack)

I realize that I could sniff the browser and just revert to jquery ui mobile swipe setup, but I think that if I could get this to work I wouldn't have to use an external library to emulate a native behavior (and native is always better).

```js
var log = function(event) {
  var log = document.querySelector('.log');
  log.innerHTML = event + "<br>" + log.innerHTML;
};
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var controlLeft = document.createElement('a');
controlLeft.className = 'control control-left';
controlLeft.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
controlLeft.innerHTML = '&lt;';
controlLeft.onclick = function() {
  log('click left');
  inner.scrollLeft++;
};
wrap.appendChild(controlLeft);
var controlRight = document.createElement('a');
controlRight.className = 'control control-right';
controlRight.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
controlRight.innerHTML = '&gt;';
controlRight.onclick = function() {
  log('click right');
  inner.scrollLeft--;
};
wrap.appendChild(controlRight);
var darken1 = document.createElement('div');
var darken2 = document.createElement('div');
darken1.className = 'darken';
darken2.className = 'darken';
items[0].appendChild(darken1);
items[2].appendChild(darken2);
var getWidth = function(element) {
  return Number(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', '')) + 1;
};
wrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
inner.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
inner.style.overflowX = 'auto';
wrap.style.height = inner.scrollHeight + 'px';
window.onresize = function() {
  wrap.style.height = inner.scrollHeight + 'px';
  inner.scrollLeft = 0;
  inner.scrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
};
inner.scrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
oldScroll = inner.scrollLeft;
inner.onscroll = function() {
  if (inner.scrollLeft < oldScroll) {
    log('scroll right');
    inner.appendChild(inner.querySelector('.item:first-child'));
    inner.querySelector('.item:first-child').appendChild(darken1);
    inner.querySelector('.item:nth-child(3)').appendChild(darken2);
  } else if (inner.scrollLeft > oldScroll) {
    log('scroll left');
    var first = inner.querySelector('.item:first-child');
    var last = inner.querySelector('.item:last-child');
    inner.insertBefore(last, first);
    inner.querySelector('.item:first-child').appendChild(darken1);
    inner.querySelector('.item:nth-child(3)').appendChild(darken2);
  }
  inner.scrollLeft = 0;
  inner.scrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
  oldScroll = inner.scrollLeft;
};
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.control {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
.control-left {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.control-right {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.inner {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  white-space: initial;
  padding-bottom: 33.3333%;
  width: 50%;
}
.item .darken {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.item[data-n="2"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/animals);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="3"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/business);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="4"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/cats);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="5"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/city);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="6"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/food);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="7"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/nightlife);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="8"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/fashion);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="9"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/people);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="10"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/nature);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="11"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/sports);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="12"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/technics);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="13"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/transport);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item" data-n="2"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="4"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="5"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="6"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="7"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="8"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="9"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="10"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="11"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="12"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="13"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="log">
</div>
```

Comment: What I noticed was that it was working fine on my laptop. I was using dell's software to scroll, and it worked perfectly. Aside from it scrolling really fast, it's fine as far as I see it.

Comment: I'll try to test it out though.

Comment: Ok, do you mean that the pictures are scrolling too fast? Because it does seem a bit fast.

Comment: Well, it looks you handled it, but I'm going to try to improve it.

Comment: Well, kinda stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue temporarily, I wrapped the function in a timeout. The timeout can be as little as 1 millisecond. I don't know why but changing the content and setting scrollLeft at the exact event of the scroll causes the browser to not reset the scroll bar.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/zujxaqy3/31/))

```
inner.onscroll = function() {
  window.clearTimeout(window.updateTimeout);
  window.updateTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (inner.scrollLeft < oldScroll) {
      log('scroll right');
      inner.appendChild(inner.querySelector('.item:first-child'));
    } else if (inner.scrollLeft > oldScroll) {
      log('scroll left')
      var first = inner.querySelector('.item:first-child');
      var last = inner.querySelector('.item:last-child');
      inner.insertBefore(last, first);
    }
    inner.querySelector('.item:first-child').appendChild(darken1);
    inner.querySelector('.item:nth-child(3)').appendChild(darken2);
    inner.scrollLeft = 0;
    inner.scrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
    oldScroll = inner.scrollLeft;
  }, 1);
};
```

While this does "fix" the issue, I think it is a hack. I'm leaving this question open to see if I can get a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to modify the property that you are using to check if the first or the last element need to be moved, you are also modifying the same info again, so you will get an unexpected behaviour.

Your trick to add a timeout gave the impression of be the solution because it give some time to the program, so it can serialize the information changes.

I've made some changes in your code and it doesn't uses timeout. But, because of the nature of the scroll event, depending on which configuration the user has in its scroll behaviour, one different amount of slides will be scrolled.

So I recommend that you add some verification, which can be a timer (hahahahaha...), but only to toggle a boolean to let the scroll handler go. Like the snnipet below:

```
inner.onscroll = function(e) {
    if (!canScroll) {
        return;
    }

    canScroll = false;

    setTimeout(function () {
        canScroll = true;
    }, 300);

    if (inner.scrollLeft < oldScrollLeft) {
    // ...
```

Before you ask, the sense of delay that `inner.scrollLeft = 0` then `inner.scrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;` provides is because of this overprocessing that the original program force the browser to do.

```js
var log = function(event) {
  var log = document.querySelector('.log');
  log.innerHTML = event + "<br>" + log.innerHTML;
};
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var controlLeft = document.createElement('a');
controlLeft.className = 'control control-left';
controlLeft.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
controlLeft.innerHTML = '&lt;';
controlLeft.onclick = function() {
  log('click left');
  inner.scrollLeft++;
};
wrap.appendChild(controlLeft);
var controlRight = document.createElement('a');
controlRight.className = 'control control-right';
controlRight.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
controlRight.innerHTML = '&gt;';
controlRight.onclick = function() {
  log('click right');
  inner.scrollLeft--;
};
wrap.appendChild(controlRight);
var darken1 = document.createElement('div');
var darken2 = document.createElement('div');
darken1.className = 'darken';
darken2.className = 'darken';
items[0].appendChild(darken1);
items[2].appendChild(darken2);
var getWidth = function(element) {
  return Math.floor(Number(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', '')));
};
wrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
inner.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
inner.style.overflowX = 'auto';
wrap.style.height = inner.scrollHeight + 'px';
var oldScrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
var oldScrollWidth = inner.scrollWidth;
window.onresize = function() {
  wrap.style.height = inner.scrollHeight + 'px';
  oldScrollWidth = inner.scrollWidth;
  oldScrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
  inner.scrollLeft = oldScrollLeft;
};
inner.scrollLeft = getWidth(items[0]) / 2;
inner.onscroll = function(e) {
  if (inner.scrollLeft < oldScrollLeft) {
    log('scroll right');
    inner.appendChild(inner.querySelector('.item:first-child'));
    inner.querySelector('.item:first-child').appendChild(darken1);
    inner.querySelector('.item:nth-child(3)').appendChild(darken2);
  } else if (inner.scrollLeft > oldScrollLeft) {
    log('scroll left');
    var first = inner.querySelector('.item:first-child');
    var last = inner.querySelector('.item:last-child');
    inner.insertBefore(last, first);
    inner.querySelector('.item:first-child').appendChild(darken1);
    inner.querySelector('.item:nth-child(3)').appendChild(darken2);
    inner.scrollLeft = 0;
  }

  inner.scrollLeft = oldScrollLeft;
};
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.control {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
.control-left {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.control-right {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.inner {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  white-space: initial;
  padding-bottom: 33.3333%;
  width: 50%;
}
.item .darken {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.item[data-n="2"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/animals);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="3"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/business);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="4"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/cats);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="5"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/city);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="6"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/food);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="7"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/nightlife);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="8"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/fashion);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="9"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/people);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="10"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/nature);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="11"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/sports);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="12"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/technics);
  background-size: cover;
}
.item[data-n="13"] {
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/transport);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item" data-n="2"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="4"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="5"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="6"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="7"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="8"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="9"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="10"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="11"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="12"></div>
    <div class="item" data-n="13"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="log">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry for the delay... well, I did an eyes closed shot, because I don't have a mobile test suite, even a gadget here with me... mine is under repair. There's still many other ways to do it and I think that deal with the scroll, listening to the event while changing its values, its the worst shot, but I've tried that too to avoid a huge refactor on your code. I've made cylindric carousel several times. The best approach is clone the elements to an odd number, center one and deal with it like an array traversing. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007928/, and adapt it.

Comment: Well, I really encourage you to use another approach. A NodeList isn't an array, sure, was a misconception of mine. But the scroll, to be the handler and the reference, as well... Another thing to mention is about the restrictions over the dimensions of things on mobile, if there's some limit about the sizes, processing modifications to improve performance, etc... Try to print a counter, over each scroll made, in vertical/horizontal positions... This is about iOS, but can be useful: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/.